# Open and display txt matrix in python and select specific part

Tags: python, matrix

I really new in Python and as my first task I would like to import a text file in Python. The file contains a matrix of **m*n** elements.
After importing the text I would like to display the whole matrix and only part of the matrix. For example the first **x** lines and **y** column.

I've tried with

```
matrix = open ('myfile.txt')
print(matrix)
print(matrix[0:x,0:y])
```

But the code dosn't work.

Comment: Can you add an example of your file ?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use `numpy` and its [loadtxt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) function.

If you don't want to rely on numpy, here's what you should know: [open](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open) returns a file object. To access the file's data, you need to use some methods of file objects, usually `read`, `readline`, `readlines`.

Let's say `myfile.txt` looks like this:

```
4 5 8 9
5 6 4 7
4 2 3 1
```

Using `numpy`, you can have your matrix read in a one-liner: `matrix = np.loadtxt("myfile.txt")`, given that you propertly `import`ed the `numpy` module using `import numpy as np`

Using only built-ins, this would look something like:

```
matrix = []
with open("/tmp/myfile.txt", 'r') as file_handler:
    for line in file_handler:
        if line.strip():
             matrix += [line.strip().split(" ")]
```

and you end up with a list of lists, which is probably less useful than a numpy array if you're working with matrices.

In either case you can then split and show the parts you are interested using `print(matrix[:y,:x])`.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it by using `numpy.matrix`, This will print only the x rows and y columns from your file. If you want to print the entire matrix remove the last.

```
import numpy
with open("j.txt", 'r') as f:
   l = [i.strip("\n").split() for i in f.readlines()]
x = 3
y = 3
print(numpy.matrix(l)[:x,:y])
```

If you want to assing to a variable you do like this :

```
a = numpy.matrix(l)[:x,:y]
print(a)
```

Comment: Thank you, using the function print(numpy.matrix(l)[:,x,:,y]) i can select my data and even plot them using the function plt.plot(....).   In the case i want to assign a specif name to a part of the matrix can i use the command  a = numpy.matrix(l)[:,x,:,y]?

Comment: @vittorio yeah like the same `a = numpy.matrix(l)[:x,:y]`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, using the function 
print(numpy.matrix(l)[:,x,:,y]) 
i can select my data and even plot them using the function plt.plot(....).

In the case i want to assign a specif name to a part of the matrix, can i use the command

a = numpy.matrix(l)[:,x,:,y]?

Comment: try to avoiding put questions on answer section , you can add if you find an answer by your own